# "Undefined control sequence \maketitle" & "Paragraph ended before \abstract was complete" errors

Tags: errors

I am using this bioinformatics template. I am trying to compile it but can't seem to resolve these two errors.

About the undefined control sequence error, it seems it is caused by a wrong command. \maketitle is valid but it is still giving an error.

About the paragraph ended before \abstract was complete error, I read it could be because of imbalanced braces. That's not the case either.

Here's the code I am using.

```
\documentclass{bioinfo}
\copyrightyear{2005}
\pubyear{2005}

\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\firstpage{1}

\title[short Title]{This is a title}
\author[Sample \textit{et~al}]{Corresponding Author\,$^{1,*}$, Co-Author\,$^{2}$ and Co-Author\,$^2$\footnote{to whom correspondence should be addressed}}
\address{$^{1}$Department of XXXXXXX, Address XXXX etc.\\
    $^{2}$Department of XXXXXXXX, Address XXXX etc.}

\history{Received on XXXXX; revised on XXXXX; accepted on XXXXX}

\editor{Associate Editor: XXXXXXX}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}

    \section{Motivation:}
    Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
    Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text.

    \section{Results:}
    Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text

    \section{Availability:}
    Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text

    \section{Contact:} \href{name@bio.com}{name@bio.com}
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}

Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text. Figure~\ref{fig:01} shows that the above method  Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text.  \citep{Bag01} wants to know about  text follows.

\begin{equation}
\sum x+ y =Z\label{eq:01}
\end{equation}


\section{Approach}

Equation~(\ref{eq:01}) Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text. Figure \ref{fig:02} shows that the above method  Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text.  \citealp{Boffelli03} might want to know about  text text text text 


\begin{methods}
    \section{Methods}

    Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text. Figure \ref{fig:02} shows that the above method  Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text.  \citealp{Boffelli03} might want to know about  text text text text
    Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text. Figure \ref{fig:02} shows that the above method  Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text.  \citealp{Boffelli03} might want to know about  text text text text
    Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text. Figure \ref{fig:02} shows that the above method  Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text.  \citealp{Boffelli03} might want to know about  text text text text

    \begin{itemize}
        \item for bulleted list, use itemize
        \item for bulleted list, use itemize
        \item for bulleted list, use itemize
    \end{itemize}


    Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text. Figure \ref{fig:02} shows that the above method  Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text.  \citealp{Boffelli03} might want to know about  text text text text
    Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text. Figure \ref{fig:02} shows that the above method  Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text.  \citealp{Boffelli03} might want to know about  text text text text
    Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text. Figure \ref{fig:02} shows that the above method  Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text.  \citealp{Boffelli03} might want to know about  text text text text
    Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text. Figure \ref{fig:02} shows that the above method  Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text.  \citealp{Boffelli03} might want to know about  text text text text
    Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text.


    Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text. Figure \ref{fig:02} shows that the above method  Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text.  \citealp{Boffelli03} might want to know about  text text text text
    Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text. Figure \ref{fig:02} shows that the above method  Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text.  \citealp{Boffelli03} might want to know about  text text text text
    Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text. Figure \ref{fig:02} shows that the above method  Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text.  \citealp{Boffelli03} might want to know about  text text text text



    Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text. Figure \ref{fig:02} shows that the above method  Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text.  \citealp{Boffelli03} might want to know about  text text text text
    Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text. Figure \ref{fig:02} shows that the above method  Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text.  \citealp{Boffelli03} might want to know about  text text text text
    Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text. Figure \ref{fig:02} shows that the above method  Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text.  \citealp{Boffelli03} might want to know about  text text text text


    Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text. Figure \ref{fig:02} shows that the above method  Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text.  \citealp{Boffelli03} might want to know about  text text text text
    Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text. Figure \ref{fig:02} shows that the above method  Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text.  \citealp{Boffelli03} might want to know about  text text text text
    Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text. Figure \ref{fig:02} shows that the above method  Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text.  \citealp{Boffelli03} might want to know about  text text text text



    \begin{table}[!t]
        \processtable{This is table caption\label{Tab:01}}
        {\begin{tabular}{llll}\toprule
                head1 & head2 & head3 & head4\\\midrule
                row1 & row1 & row1 & row1\\
                row2 & row2 & row2 & row2\\
                row3 & row3 & row3 & row3\\
                row4 & row4 & row4 & row4\\\botrule
            \end{tabular}}{This is a footnote}
        \end{table}

    \end{methods}

    \begin{figure}[!tpb]%figure1
        %\centerline{\includegraphics{fig01.eps}}
        \caption{Caption, caption.}\label{fig:01}
    \end{figure}

    \begin{figure}[!tpb]%figure2
        %\centerline{\includegraphics{fig02.eps}}
        \caption{Caption, caption.}\label{fig:02}
    \end{figure}

    \section{Discussion}

    Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text. Figure \ref{fig:02} shows that the above method  Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text.  \citealp{Boffelli03} might want to know about  text text text text
    Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text. Figure \ref{fig:02} shows that the above method  Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text.  \citealp{Boffelli03} might want to know about  text text text text
    Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text.


    Table~\ref{Tab:01} shows that Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text. Figure \ref{fig:02} shows that
    the above method Text Text. Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text. Figure \ref{fig:02} shows that
    the above method Text Text. Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text. Figure \ref{fig:02} shows that
    the above method Text Text.


    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %
    %     please remove the " % " symbol from \centerline{\includegraphics{fig01.eps}}
    %     as it may ignore the figures.
    %
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    \section{Conclusion}

    (Table~\ref{Tab:01}) Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text. Figure \ref{fig:02} shows that the above method  Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text.  \citealp{Boffelli03} might want to know about  text text text text
    Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text. Figure \ref{fig:02} shows that the above method  Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text.  \citealp{Boffelli03} might want to know about  text text text text
    Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text. Figure \ref{fig:02} shows that the above method  Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text.



    Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text. Figure \ref{fig:02} shows that the above method  Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text.  \citealp{Boffelli03} might want to know about  text text text text


    \begin{enumerate}
        \item this is item, use enumerate
        \item this is item, use enumerate
        \item this is item, use enumerate
    \end{enumerate}

    Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text. Figure \ref{fig:02} shows that the above method  Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text.  \citealp{Boffelli03} might want to know about  text text text text
    Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text. Figure \ref{fig:02} shows that the above method  Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text.  \citealp{Boffelli03} might want to know about  text text text text
    Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text.


    Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text. Figure \ref{fig:02} shows that the above method  Text Text Text Text


    \section*{Acknowledgement}
    Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text.  \citealp{Boffelli03} might want to know about  text text text text

    \paragraph{Funding\textcolon} Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text.

    %\bibliographystyle{natbib}
    %\bibliographystyle{achemnat}
    %\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
    %\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
    %\bibliographystyle{bioinformatics}
    %
    %\bibliographystyle{plain}
    %
    %\bibliography{Document}


    \begin{thebibliography}{}
        \bibitem[Bofelli {\it et~al}., 2000]{Boffelli03} Bofelli,F., Name2, Name3 (2003) Article title, {\it Journal Name}, {\bf 199}, 133-154.

        \bibitem[Bag {\it et~al}., 2001]{Bag01} Bag,M., Name2, Name3 (2001) Article title, {\it Journal Name}, {\bf 99}, 33-54.

        \bibitem[Yoo \textit{et~al}., 2003]{Yoo03}
        Yoo,M.S. \textit{et~al}. (2003) Oxidative stress regulated genes
        in nigral dopaminergic neurnol cell: correlation with the known
        pathology in Parkinson's disease. \textit{Brain Res. Mol. Brain
            Res.}, \textbf{110}(Suppl. 1), 76--84.

        \bibitem[Lehmann, 1986]{Leh86}
        Lehmann,E.L. (1986) Chapter title. \textit{Book Title}. Vol.~1, 2nd edn. Springer-Verlag, New York.

        \bibitem[Crenshaw and Jones, 2003]{Cre03}
        Crenshaw, B.,III, and Jones, W.B.,Jr (2003) The future of clinical
        cancer management: one tumor, one chip. \textit{Bioinformatics},
        doi:10.1093/bioinformatics/btn000.

        \bibitem[Auhtor \textit{et~al}. (2000)]{Aut00}
        Auhtor,A.B. \textit{et~al}. (2000) Chapter title. In Smith, A.C.
        (ed.), \textit{Book Title}, 2nd edn. Publisher, Location, Vol. 1, pp.
        ???--???.

        \bibitem[Bardet, 1920]{Bar20}
        Bardet, G. (1920) Sur un syndrome d'obesite infantile avec
        polydactylie et retinite pigmentaire (contribution a l'etude des
        formes cliniques de l'obesite hypophysaire). PhD Thesis, name of
        institution, Paris, France.

    \end{thebibliography}
\end{document
```

Here's a link to the bioinfo.cls file.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/a65ubzzauuquxvf/bioinfo.cls?dl=0

Comment: Where can we find this `bioinfo.cls`?

Comment: You cannot have an empty line in the abstract and you shoul not have a section in the abstract.

Comment: You might want to take a look at package `blindtext` or `lipsum`. All this `text text text text` is boring and bloating the quite extensive example even more.

Comment: That got resolved. But still getting the "Undefined control sequence. \maketitle" error.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I added the link to the bioinfo.cls in the question.

Comment: You are lying, it is not `\maketitle` that is undefined. Or rather your editor hides the truth from you. You have to define `\abstract{my abstract here}` and `\corresp{corresponding author}` and it works (if you have the image for the title).

Answer (score 1):

In the bioinfo.cls there is a commented environment also named `abstract`.

```
%\newenvironment{abstract}{%
%  \begingroup
%  \let\section\absection
%  \fontfamily{\sfdefault}\fontsize{10}{12}\sffamily\selectfont
%  {\fontseries{b}\selectfont Abstract}\par}
%{\endgroup\bigskip\@afterheading\@afterindentfalse\vskip 12pt plus 3pt minus 1pt}
```

This can be an old version of the class and the template provided has not been updated. That is the reason why you have to define 
`\abstract{my abstract here}` and `\corresp{corresponding author}` before the beginning of the document (as mentioned by @Johannes_B)

Thus you have to have this structure:

```
\history{Received on XXXXX; revised on XXXXX; accepted on XXXXX}    
\editor{Associate Editor: XXXXXXX
\corresp{TEST}
\abstract{Short version of your abstract.}

\begin{document}
\firstpage{1}
\begin{abstract}
    The long version of your abstract.
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
```

Comment: I am still having the same issue and it could not be solved with your structure. Any other hints? The current version of the latex template can be found here (https://static.primary.prod.gcms.the-infra.com/static/site/bioinformatics/document/cabios-template.zip?node=0dd78a73d16bf6a2b799&version=23584:a9838eca83b4c0bcf4a3)